# Cannot get istanbul to ignore angular @Input set function

Tags: angular, istanbul

none of these ignore the relevant function. how do you ignore an input set function in ng2? thx

```
/* istanbul ignore next */
@Input()
set pageOffset(pageOffset: number) {
    this.pageOffsetSetter(pageOffset);
}

@Input()
/* istanbul ignore next */
set pageOffset(pageOffset: number) {
    this.pageOffsetSetter(pageOffset);
}

@Input()
set /* istanbul ignore next */ pageOffset(pageOffset: number) {
    this.pageOffsetSetter(pageOffset);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was because the ts to js conversion was messing up the position of

/* istanbul ignore next */

so i had no choice but to switch to using ngOnChanges instead :(